# Converting a lattice in to mesh, best way to connect the edges?

Tags: python, lattice

I am writing a script to convert a lattice into a poly mesh.
I was wondering if there is a better optimized way to create the edges the way I am doing in the code below:

import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
lattice= bpy.data.objects["Lattice"]

```
u = lattice.data.points_u
v = lattice.data.points_v
w = lattice.data.points_w

w_cap = u*v*(w-1)
v_cap = v*u
verts=[]
edges=[]
faces=[]


for point in lattice.data.points:
    verts.append(point.co)

x=0


for i in range(0,len(verts)):
    if i % u: 
        edges.append((i-1, i)) #creating u edges

    if (i-x) % (v_cap ):
        edges.append((i, i-u)) #creating v edges
    if (x+1) % u:
        x+=1
    else:
        x=0


    if i<w_cap:
        edges.append((i, i+v_cap)) #creating w edges


mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Poly_mesh')
object = bpy.data.objects.new('Poly_Lattice', mesh)
mesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)

bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link (object)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you! 
Maurizio